# Making post request for HttpRequest an HttpClient in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making post request in angular2 . I am using this as I want to track progress precentage

```
const postReq = new HttpRequest('POST','urlendpoint', formData, {
  reportProgress: true,
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
});
```

Where `formData` is data that is to be submitted .

Issue with this request is that it is not sending post parameters and also method is `OPTIONS` instead of `POST` .
[image]

Can anybody explain me what is wrong with this request and how to fix it .?

Comment: try using `JSON.stringify(formData)`

Comment: this is a preflight request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
this should be followed by actual POST request if the server allows it.

Comment: @AnkitSaroch Can you please explain it with little bit of code ?I am using cloned request now `const clonedPostReq = postReq.clone({body:videoformData,setHeaders:{'content-type':'mutipart/form-data'}});` It is sending post request but I am getting http 415 unsupported media type

Comment: have you tested your API using postman ?, this error is because server is not allowed to hit this API, and `option` is because this is preflighted request.

Comment: @PardeepJain API is fine and well tested .It is just that I am missing out something when sending request

Comment: try using the http module from angular, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient